# Core Data to-one relationship - is foreign reference indexed?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I'd like to apply a filter to child objects belonging to a set of parent objects in a list.

So take example Person and PersonInterest. Relationship Person<-->>PersonInterest. PersonInterest only has one property that maps to an enum value (small number).

I have a huge store database and have hand-picked a few Person objects and have their ObjectIDs in an array. Now I want to filter on those having a given interest identified as say 1.

Predicates could be 
1)fetch PersonInterest

```
@"(person IN %@) AND (interestType == 1)",personObjectIDList
```

2)or fetch Person

```
@"(self IN %@) AND (ANY personInterests.interestType == 1)",personObjectIDList
```

Given that each person has an average of 5 interests, are both queries efficient?

I may later want to match on a multiple interests so query 2 is my preferred choice e.g.:

```
@"(self IN %@) AND (ANY personInterests.interestType IN (1,2))",personObjectIDList //this may not work due to predicate restrictions for to-many
```

..... and how would these compare to a property on Person storing a JSON list of interestTypes where I pad with first and last elements 0 (e.g. '[0,1,4,3,0]' ):

```
@"(self IN %@) AND (jsonInterestType like '*,1,*')",personObjectIDList
```

Comment: If you already have an array of objects, why not using a predicate to filter the array instead of performing another fetch? To measure the performance difference of your different approaches use Instruments.

Comment: @Martin Brugger - Wouldn't that fire multiple faults for each Person i query? ... I'll try with Instruments but is there any profiling for database access and number of rows fetched?

Comment: Each person would have to be unfaulted of course. Running instruments on the simulator allows analyzing core data.

Comment: @MartinBrugger - thanks for the info. I found the core data bits in Instruments. ... I did a schema check on the db generated and an index is created on the to-one relationship reference.